# Serializing a object with an image to be saved to SQL database

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, sql-server-2000, binary-data

I have the following object:

```
[Serializable]
public class ExampleImage
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

I store this in a `List<ExampleImage>` which I then pass to the following function to serialize it to a string:

```
static string SerializeObjectToXmlString(object o)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
    System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    serializer.Serialize(writer, o);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

I then pass this serialized string to a stored procedure in **SQL2000** as an `NTEXT` which then handled for inserting it into the database:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempImages
FROM OpenXML(@iDoc, '/ArrayOfExampleImage/ExampleImage')
WITH ([Filename] VARCHAR(255) './Filename', [Content] IMAGE './Content')
```

The problem I am having is the image is getting trashed.  The `btye[]` is not getting saved properly to the DB.  The other fields are just fine.  This is the first time I have attempt to send a binary data via XML to SQL so I am most likely doing something wrong at this point.  Is my `SerializeObjectToXmlString` function the problem and it is not handling the serialization of a `byte[]` properly, maybe the `OpenXML` SQL function or even the fact that I am sending the XML in as an `NTEXT` param.  I would expect the serialize function to encode the binary properly but I could be wrong.

Any idea what is the issue or maybe a better approach to saving a bunch of images at once?

**Edit:** I think what is happening, is the serializer is making the `byte[]` into a base64 string, which is then getting passed along to the stored proc as base64.  I am then saving this base64 string into an Image field in SQL and reading it out as a `btye[]`.  So I think I need to somehow get it from base64 to a `byte[]` before inserting it in my table?

**Edit:** I am starting to think my only option is to change the stored proc to just do 1 image at a time and not use XML and just pass in the `byte[]` as an `Image` type and wrap all the calls in a transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gaidin suggested, base64 is the best option. It's the usual way of writing binary data to XML. You can use the following code :

```
public class ExampleImage
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Content")]
    public string ContentBase64
    {
        get { return Convert.ToBase64String(Content); }
        set { Content = Convert.FromBase64String(value); }
    }
}
```

(by the way, the `Serializable` attribute has no meaning for XML serialization)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of serializing it to XML, I would serialize it to a byte[] and store that in varbinary(MAX) type field in your DB.

Comment: I am storing parts of the data in regular fields etc.  The example is a trimmed down version of the real objects to make it more simple.  The the file content is the only binary data, I still need to get the other data saved to the DB as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting it to base64, then saving it to TEXT field or something.